# Can I Use e.PrintStackTrace() or Breakpoints When Using Android USB Device?

Tags: android, debugging

In the Android app I'm currently working on I have all my try/catches to print out a stack trace but when using a physical android device via USB these errors do not seem to get printed. Further more, when I attempt to create a debug log on the device, it never shows up. My assumption is that I have to start relying on Log.d and print everything to the logcat. Is this correct?

Edit: I should also mention that these stack traces appear when using an emulator as well.

Also, I have noticed when debugging on a physical device when I hit break points it locks the application but it does not allow me to continue with debugging, a.k.a pass over the break point. Is this an error or simply how it preforms? Break points work fine on the genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something in wrong way, be sure not to debug and look for logs at the same time and be sure you are using right filter at loging.
And at last be sure that you turn on debug mode on at your release version of app(or what version you are using at device).

Comment: I don't follow. When running the emulator, the PrintStackTraces come up in real time? Are you saying I can not view the printstacktraces in real time on a physical device? Everything is in debug mode, I have it set to wait for the debugger to attach before running.

Comment: No, you would see PrintStackTraces in real time. Look again at Log filter and don't forget to restart AS.

Answer (score 0):

For the logs, you should have to check is the log is enable, by using the following steps in eclipse:

* Go in **Windows -> Preferences**.

* After that, select **Android -> LogCat**.

* And set the option "**Show logcat view if message priority is atleast:**" to "**VERBOSE**".